# Need help to setup polymorphic associations in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, relational-database, polymorphic-associations

I have a Contact model that has basic information (name, address, phone number) and I will have more specific contacts that will have more information in addition to the info on the Contact class: Witness, Attorney, and Client

I have two questions.  One, how do I setup the models so that when I want to invoke an instance of Contact class, I can access the Witness, Attorney, or Client info depending on what type of contact it is.  Second, I have other models that will have associations with the Contact class.  For instance, a Case has one Contact (which is an Attorney) and Case has another Contact (which is a Client); a Task has one Contact (which can be any of the types of Contacts); an Event has many Contacts.

I was just curious as to what the best practice is to setup this type of model. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the has one through relation to setup the relationships.

case.rb

```
has_one :lawyer, through: :contact
has_one :attorney, through: :contact
```

How to setup the polymorphic association.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contactable, polymorphic: true
end

class Attorney < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts, as: :contactable
end

class Lawyer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts, as: :contactable
end
```

You can check the polymophism [Polymorphic Association Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.)

To add this in your form you'll need to build the associations in your new action in the controller

```
@case = Case.new
@case.build_attorney
@case.build_lawyer
```

There's another good reference here [Association Build Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference)

Comment: how would the form be on the cases page?  how can I refer to Client and Attorney on the form?

Comment: I added a bit more in the answer. Hope it helps.